# Regular Expression validation for Afghanistan Phone Numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation

I want that my user should only enter the ph# in 937XXXXXXXX Afghanistan international number format.

So far I have written below code but it is not working as I wanted to:

```
Private Function Valid_Contact_No(ByVal Contact_No As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[937][0-9]{1,11}$")
    ' Confirm there is text in the control.
    If txtContact_no.Text.Length = 0 Then
        errorMessage = "Contact No# is required (allowed format: 937XXXXXXXX)"
        Return False
    End If
    If txtContact_no.Text.Length > 11 Then
        errorMessage = "Contact_No Can not be more than 11 digits (allowed format: 937XXXXXXXX)"
        Return False
    End If
    If (regex.IsMatch(txtContact_no.Text)) Then
        errorMessage = ""
        Return True
    End If
    errorMessage = "A valid Contact No# is required" + ControlChars.Cr
    Return False
End Function
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `937` code should be outside the brackets:

```
"^937[0-9]{0,11}$|7[0-9]{0,9}$"
```

Things within brackets are character sets but you want `937` as a prefix.

You need the pipe `(|)` symbol for an alteration in regex.

And as for the string length, match the regex twice and for each match check the length of the string.

Comment: @farhan Anam I just remembered to either prefix 937 or only 7! how to do that?

Comment: @Farhan Anam with 7 two digits will be omitted like this "^937[0-9]{1,11}$|7[0-9]{1,9}$" So I did it but still it accepts till 11 digits! how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> /(+93|0093)?0?7[0-9]{8}/

this is a valid regex for any of these phone numbers

```
+937XXXXXXXX

+9307XXXXXXXX

07XXXXXXXX

7XXXXXXXX

00937XXXXXXXX

009307XXXXXXXX
```

> /(+93)?0?7[0-9]{8}/

this is a valid regex for any of these phone numbers

```
+937XXXXXXXX

+9307XXXXXXXX

 07XXXXXXXX

 7XXXXXXXX
```

> /+937[0-9]{8}/

this is a valid regex for any of these phone numbers

```
+937XXXXXXXX
```

> /(\0093)?7[0-9]{8}/

this is a valid regex for any of these phone numbers

```
00937XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using jQuery and below expression is working for `+93`, `0093` and `07`.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("chkMobile", function () {
                return /((\+*)93|0093)?0?7[0-9]{8}/.test(this.value);                
            },"Mobile number is not valid.");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Afghanistan

`/^((\+|00)93|0)[2-7]\d{8}$/`

I'm not sure but in some case it will be like

`/^((\+|00)93|0)?[2-7]\d{8}$/`

if the `0` prefix or `+93` or `0093` not needed

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression validation for Afghanistan Phone Numbers

^((\+93)|(0093))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{6}$|^\d{10}$|^\d{4}-\d{6}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).